# value of length(integer), used by the free pointer

Tags: c, linux, malloc, free

As we know, the `free()` function knows how much of the memory is to be freed from the malloc'd memory by using a prefixed integer value stored just at the back of the malloc'd pointer. So I tried this code and am having two doubts:

1. If I `malloc()` 20 bytes and then print the integer value at the decremented pointer, it is showing 25 bytes. And if I `malloc()` 40 bytes, and then print the value then I get 49 bytes!
2. If I try to go beyond and print the values after my malloc'd space, every time I get a big integer value stored next to the last of the malloc'd memory. What is that value? Is it something special?

Any explanation would be appreciated.

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    int *ptr, *pr;

    ptr = (int *)malloc(20);
    pr = ptr;

    printf("value of ptr is %p", ptr);
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        ptr[i] = i + 1;
    }

    printf("now the values in malloc'd memory is\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", ptr[i]);
    }

    printf("value of ptr is %p\n", ptr);
    pr--;
    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        printf("value of pr at address  %p  is  %d\n", pr, *pr);
        pr++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, we don't know that.

Comment: To expand on what Kerrek SB said, what makes you think that this is how your `malloc` implementation keeps track of the size?

Comment: Are you using that only for academical reasons? There is no rule in C nor C++ that garantee what you are saying.

Comment: @kerrek SB,@aix,@Renan Greinert
pardon for the mistake,, i am just a beginner and i said what i have read from books or through internet...

IS IT ONE OF THE WAY TO KNOW HOW FREE() IS IMPLEMENTED??
if yes, then can u people plz. give a look to my doubt..

Comment: I expect that the value just before actually indicates size either 24 or 48, with the lowest bit used as a flag to mean something or other (maybe that the memory is allocated). The "large value" you see is possibly either uninitialized memory, or else a pointer somewhere else in the memory allocator's data structures. Kerrek is correct that in practice we don't know the details, but in principle we could check the implementation of `malloc` in glibc. You should do that, it's much more instructive to see the code (and comments) than just poke around at the data.

Answer (score 2):

1. We do not know how malloc works internally.  It can change from version to version of the runtime library.  That it hasn't (so far), it not a reason to gamble.
2. We should not depend on specific behind-the-scenes behavior of any particular implementation.  Only depend on the documented features unless you are willing to trade generality for some *worthy* purpose.

Most `malloc` implementations do, in fact, allocate an extra few words of overhead immediately before the area given to the program.  The overhead allows administrating the heap.  But is the size field 4 bytes before, or 16?  Is it a 32 bit value?  Maybe it is a scaled number of paragraphs (16-byte entries), like on iRMX86.  Does the overhead area contain forward links *and* backward links?  Maybe there is a namecheck field with the debug version of the library.

Maybe it is implemented like Snobol-68 on Cyber/NOS:  an array of structure with pointers to data and their sizes.  Program "pointers" are actually indices of the item in the array.  This is an especially efficient structure for caching and readahead purposes.

There are so many possible variations that no enduring program should rely on such details.

Possibly, you might consider writing a `lengthof(ptr)` function to include with the runtime library which returns the number of bytes requested at `malloc()`, or maybe actually allocated bytes.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably true that most `malloc` implementations have some way to find the allocated size of a pointer argument.

However, the way to do that is private to the implementation, and some `malloc` implementation *don't always allocate a prefix header* for each zone.

A common trick for implementing `malloc` is to handle differently various allocated sizes. For instance, it could handle differently

1. `malloc` of two words or less (i.e. of `2*sizeof(void*)`) since this case is very frequent (for e.g. single-linked list of pointers, like `cons` cells in Lisp).
2. `malloc` of small-sized zones, of size less than a threshold, typically the page size -in the sense of [getpagesize(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getpagesize) syscall on Linux, often 4kbytes.
3. `malloc` of large-sized zones, bigger than a page size

Some implementations take into account the actual address, by e.g. having an internal arena (segments of pages) dedicated for pairs, another allocation arena dedicated to small sized zones of size `2^n` and `3*2^n` (with e.g. `n>2 && n<10`), and the large objects actually allocated in their own arena each. Then the `malloc` implementation has some internal hash table mapping addresses (each of lower 16 bits all zero) to arenas.

So you should not assume that each malloc-ed zone has an overhead before. It could be wrong. If you need such an assumption, write your own `malloc` equivalent (or replacement) using the operating system calls (e.g. [mmap(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) on Linux).